# Injecting fields via Spring into entities loaded by Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, dependency-injection

I am looking for a way to inject certain properties via Spring in a bean that is loaded from the DB by Hibernate.

E.g.

```
class Student {
   int id; //loaded from DB
   String name; //loaded from DB
   int injectedProperty; //Inject via Spring
}
```

Can I configure Spring so that whenever Hibernate creates objects of class Student, some properties as defined in some applicationContext file are injected with the object creation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a facility for this, using [AspectJ class weaving with the `@Configurable` annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable). This will auto-wire any `new` instance of an annotated class with Spring dependencies, including objects instantiated via reflection using the likes of Hibernate.

It does require some class-loading magic, and so depends on [compatibility with your server platform](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw).

Answer (score 30):

While [the aspectj way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505421/injecting-fields-via-spring-into-entities-loaded-by-hibernate/3505484#3505484) works, I'd say the standard spring / hibernate way is to register a [LoadEventListener](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadoc/index.html?org/hibernate/event/LoadEventListener.html) (read more in the [hibernate core reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#objectstate-events), the [spring reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate) and [this thread](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-24943.html))

here is a snip from the spring sessionfactory bean definition

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    ...
    <property name="eventListeners">
        <map>
            <entry key="post-load">
                <bean class="com.foo.spring.MyLoadListener"></bean>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and here is the LoadEventListener:

```
public class MyLoadListener implements LoadEventListener{

    public void setSpringManagedProperty(String springManagedProperty){
        this.springManagedProperty = springManagedProperty;
    }
    private String springManagedProperty;

    @Override
    public void onLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType) throws HibernateException{
        if(MyEntity.class.getName().equals(event.getEntityClassName())){
            MyEntity entity = (MyEntity) event.getInstanceToLoad();
            entity.setMyCustomProperty(springManagedProperty);
        }

    }

}
```

Look mom, no aspectj needed.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to define custom user type and accessing properties from spring configuration over there. But I think you will get much better replies from others :).

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the dependency into the hibernate DAO bean for the entity and set the property on the entity before returning it from the DAO.

This will only work if you are loading the entity from the DAO