# Hibernate entity autowire

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, autowired

Can you please advice me, how can I nicely enable Spring autowiring for Hibernate entities?

Let's say I have an entity and would like to have mail-sender there:

```
@Entity
public class EmailActivity extends Activity {
    @Autowired @Transient
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    ...
}
```

Is there any better way than doing

```
AutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(
    getCurrentSession().get(Activity.class, id)
);
```

in my DAO?

thanks!

Comment: Putting a mail sender into an entity seems like an odd choice.  Can you describe a little more about why you want that approach?  It's obviously not to persist the instance since it's marked transient, and it's not because you're using a non-anemic pattern like active record (since you mention a DAO).

Why not inject the mail sender into a manager/service layer with a method exposed to pass the appropriate activity data to be emailed?

Comment: related: http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=180

Comment: I think mail sender is an infrastructure. Domain model should not depend to infrastructure code

Comment: oh, come on guys, it's just an example. Actually my EmailActivity is not real entity, it's just a wrapper (@Discriminator) over Activity and sure mail sender is not stored in Db

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible! (And it is the default style in Spring Roo!)

All what you need is to add the @Configurable annotation to your Entity. Activate the annotation in the configuration `<context:spring-configured/>` and using AspectJ weaving.

There is a Chapter in the Spring Reference: [7.8.1 Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable)

See also:

- http://www.chrissearle.org/node/285
- http://www.olivergierke.de/wordpress/2009/05/using-springs-configurable-in-three-easy-steps/

*BTW I strongly recommend to use AspectJ compile time weaving, when possible.*

Answer (score 3):

The way I do it is to use AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.

In your entity's constructor you ask the AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor to inject "this".

My comments at the end of [this article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/scala_and_spring) details the technique.   The article talks about a similar method of autowiring Hibernate entities.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a better way than using aspectj-weaving, namely using a hibernate `LoadEventListener`, explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3519895).