# Can not wire service in entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've got an entity class and few services. That works well. But now I want to use a service inside an entity. I've added `@Configurable` and `@Transient` annotation to entity class and also `<context:spring-configured />` statement to root-context.xml. Console says:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

I've checked if service field is null and yes, it is. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Entities are not Spring beans. Spring doesn't know about them, and is not responsible for their instantiation. It thus can't inject anything into them.

Calling a service from an entity is just not something you should do. The service layer uses the domain layer, but not vice-versa.

Comment: But that post says it's possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594934/hibernate-entity-autowire

Comment: And it explains how to do it. So, if you really want that (which, I repeat, is not something you should do), then follow the answer: as it says, you need to enable aspectJ instrumentation of your byte-code.